# Trying to display scope in html - angularJS/ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

Trying to display scope in html - angularJS/ionic
Trying to display the title to my web page but nothing is showing up. I'm fairly new to angular and ionic framework. If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong, it would help a ton!

Here is my controller js:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])

.controller('TodoCtrls', function($scope) {


  $scope.tasks = [
    { title: 'Collect coins' },
    { title: 'Eat mushrooms' },
    { title: 'Get high enough to grab the flag' },
    { title: 'Find the Princess' }
  ];
})
```

And my html:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Courses</ion-title>
      <h1 class="title">Todo</h1>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<script src="TodoCtrl.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>



<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="TodoCtrls">
    <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <h1>{{task.title}}</h1><br>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Did you get it working? :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Your code is basically good, but there are two issues:

1. The `ion-header` tag should be inside the `body` element
2. I'm assuming you're just including the angular.min.js in this file for testing, so you don't need something fancy. But the scripts need to be loaded in the right order. I'd put them just before the closing `</body>` tag, and switch the order so that Angular loads before your controller.

When I [change this in your example, it seems to work](http://embed.plnkr.co/AdJY6wBCQszF6HRgOtyz/). Ionic is not included anywhere so you don't get the styling of course, but the list is rendered.

Comment: So I changed it and I'm still getting nothing displayed. Is there a way you can send me that snippet of code?